# How to create custom thumbnail cover of a video?

Tags: video, thumbnails

I wish to create a custom thumbnail of my movies and other video, just like the one used by [TED talks](http://www.ted.com/).

The example below will illustrate, the video on the right handside is one of the video from [TED](http://www.ted.com/), while on the left is a normal video.

I tried fiddling with the options in KMP Player, but could not make any headway. Also a google search did not reveal much, maybe I was not phrasing it properly.

[image]

Comment: I've used Windows Media Preview. Check it here: http://www.babelsoft.net/products.htm
As for the windows side, there is not an option to do it within windows. So, in this case you have to use another tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I have been through this..

I actually followed this [Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/442855/custom-video-icon-for-a-single-video-file-in-windows-7-file-explorer?rq=1) on Superuser, which took me to searching and installing an "MP4 ID3 tag editor". Well this basically ruined my video. It did produce the desired result of the thumbnail, but the sound was lost. Later I found it to be a stupid option to try and edit MP4 tag using an MP3 tag editor (mind it, the software description did list MP4 compatibility).

After lots of trial and error, I stumbled across [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/), it a Video Player and MP4 tag editor. It works simply well. There are two versions, one paid and free. The free works well  for your purpose. It even automatically detects a image / cover in the folder of the video.

One tip, try find an image or crop the image into a square to get the desired output as illustrated in your question.

Comment: Media Monkey, yay. However, you may find unexpected behaviour if working with multiple videos in one folder. To prevent Media Monkey from applying your selected image to all videos in the folder, go to the Tools menu > Options > Library, and uncheck "Generate thumbnails for videos". See https://ccm.net/faq/19898-mediamonkey-don-t-create-thumbnails-for-videos-without-artwork

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mp3tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/en/download.html) to change the cover art of the videos like mp4 etc and [MKVToolNix GUI](https://mkvtoolnix.download/) as MP3tag does not work with the MKV file type.